# Primary keys with same names in different tables

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

- `Event` (**EID**, Semester, MName, Time, Room,...)
- `Module` (**MName**,...)
- `Eventplan` (**EID**, **SName**)
- `Subject` (**SName**, ...)

This is my DB schema. I don't understand the relation between Event <-> Eventplan <-> Subject. The bold names are primary keys. But if EID is a primary key in Event and Eventplan, which one is the primary key in their own relation?

There must be a primary key, and a foreign key in order to use them in SQL. So I really don't understand how to see which one of them has which role, when both names are equal and even marked as primary keys.

Comment: Export the DDL for these tables and list here.  You're correct in that both Event.EID and EventPlan.EID can't be primary keys and related.  They may be related in code only.  The developer may have ensured that event.EID and EventPlan.EID are both created at the same time.  Thus the fact they have the same values could be how they intended to keep them in sync.  However, if they did that, it's dangerous and the keys could easily fall out of sync...

Comment: I am sorry xQbert, but this is not developed yet. It is just pure theory which I got from someone. So if they cant be primary keys, what do I have to change here that this could work?

Comment: That depends on the relationships.  Do events have only one plan? Do plans associate to only one event?   Can events exists without plans and vice versa?  Without knowing this we can't say if the EventPlan.EID should be stored on Event table, or if the Event.EID should be stored on the eventPlan Table; or if an associative table is needed.  (I'd rename eventPlan.EID to EPID as well to avoid confusion later)

Comment: One eventplan has many events and events only have one plan. They cannot exist without plans and vise versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theory is a bit off on the Event Plan...

Given that a plan can be used for any number of events but an event always has only 1 plan...

I'd structure like this:

**PLAN**
PID, PName.... etc..,

**Event**
EID, Semester, MID, SID, PID, Time, Room

**Module**
MID, Mname...

**Subject**
SID, SName

This assumes the following:

- Plans belong to Zero or many events.
- Modules belong to Zero or may events.
- Subjects below to zero or many events.
- Events have exactly one module, subject and plan.
- Fields containing ID are PK or FK.. Those listed first are PK, those listed later are FK.

I interject MID, and SID because if names change you have to update both tables.  In this case MID and SID become surrogate keys not dependent if names change.